# Difference between subscribe and computed in knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

Whats the main difference between using a `computed` function and a `subscribe` function in knockout.js?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

got it working using this :)

```
function drawChart() {
    var sample_data = document.getElementById('sample_data').value;
    var data2 = eval("["+sample_data+"]");
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2);


    var options = {
        hAxis: {title: 'Age',  minValue: 0,maxValue:105},
        vAxis: {title:'Savings', minValue: 0,maxValue:2500000},
        width: 960, height: 300,
        colors: ['#4a82bd'],
        legend:'none'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);



}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function buffer(){
    setTimeout(function () {drawChart();}, 100);
}


function ViewModel() {
    var self =this;
    self.rangeSelect = ko.observable('0%');

    self.dataGetter = ko.computed(function(){
        var range = self.rangeSelect();
        if(range=='0%'){
            return "['Age','Savings'],"+
                       "[25,0],"+
                       "[26,2738],"+
                       "[27,5834],"+
                       "[28,9278],"+
                       "[29,13191],"+
                       "[30,17592],"+
                       "[31,22288],"+
                       "[32,27418],"+
                       "[33,32993],"+
                       "[34,38954],"+
                       "[35,45304],"+
                       "[36,52127],"+
                       "[37,59254],"+
                       "[38,66663],"+
                       "[39,74535],"+
                       "[40,83148],"+
                       "[41,91537],"+
                       "[42,100823],"+
                       "[43,110002],"+
                       "[44,119837],"+
                       "[45,129897],"+
                       "[46,141052],"+
                       "[47,152166],"+
                       "[48,163757],"+
                       "[49,175561],"+
                       "[50,188520],"+
                       "[51,200952],"+
                       "[52,214325],"+
                       "[53,228245],"+
                       "[54,243532],"+
                       "[55,259149],"+
                       "[56,274371],"+
                       "[57,290571],"+
                       "[58,307564],"+
                       "[59,322976],"+
                       "[60,340957],"+
                       "[61,358337],"+
                       "[62,375345],"+
                       "[63,392495],"+
                       "[64,410609],"+
                       "[65,428638],"+
                       "[66,400252],"+
                       "[67,370044],"+
                       "[68,340162],"+
                       "[69,306514],"+
                       "[70,274417],"+
                       "[71,239492],"+
                       "[72,205637],"+
                       "[73,169858],"+
                       "[74,133103],"+
                       "[75,97019],"+
                       "[76,58116],"+
                       "[77,19529],"+
                       "[78,0],"+
                       "[79,0],"+
                       "[80,0],"+
                       "[81,0],"+
                       "[82,0],"+
                       "[83,0],"+
                       "[84,0],"+
                       "[85,0],"+
                       "[86,0],"+
                       "[87,0],"+
                       "[88,0],"+
                       "[89,0]";

        }

        if(range=='30%'){
            return "['Age','Savings'],"+
                "[25,0],"+
                "[26,2763],"+
                "[27,5903],"+
                "[28,9425],"+
                "[28,13446],"+
                "[30,17979],"+
                "[31,22878],"+
                "[32,28219],"+
                "[33,34039],"+
                "[34,40228],"+
                "[35,46859],"+
                "[36,54017],"+
                "[37,61553],"+
                "[38,69396],"+
                "[39,77845],"+
                "[40,86793],"+
                "[41,95891],"+
                "[42,105723],"+
                "[43,115624],"+
                "[44,126388],"+
                "[45,137413],"+
                "[46,149463],"+
                "[47,161610],"+
                "[48,174637],"+
                "[49,188323],"+
                "[50,201752],"+
                "[51,216495],"+
                "[52,232232],"+
                "[53,249291],"+
                "[54,266171],"+
                "[55,284657],"+
                "[56,303552],"+
                "[57,322324],"+
                "[58,342561],"+
                "[59,360749],"+
                "[60,384075],"+
                "[61,407563],"+
                "[62,430104],"+
                "[63,452547],"+
                "[64,478876],"+
                "[65,502663],"+
                "[66,482031],"+
                "[67,460505],"+
                "[68,436020],"+
                "[69,410875],"+
                "[70,385525],"+
                "[71,357512],"+
                "[72,331003],"+
                "[73,302766],"+
                "[74,270112],"+
                "[75,239441],"+
                "[76,204458],"+
                "[77,170147],"+
                "[78,135332],"+
                "[79,99096],"+
                "[80,60097],"+
                "[81,20800],"+
                "[82,0],"+
                "[83,0],"+
                "[84,0],"+
                "[85,0],"+
                "[86,0],"+
                "[87,0],"+
                "[88,0],"+
                "[89,0]";


        }

        if(range=='40%'){
            return     "['Age','Savings'],"+
                "[25,0],"+
                "[26,2770],"+
                "[27,5923],"+
                "[28,9475],"+
                "[29,13352],"+
                "[30,18098],"+
                "[31,23072],"+
                "[32,28500],"+
                "[33,34380],"+
                "[34,40634],"+
                "[35,47414],"+
                "[36,54661],"+
                "[37,62364],"+
                "[38,70244],"+
                "[39,78957],"+
                "[40,88011],"+
                "[41,97367],"+
                "[42,107449],"+
                "[43,117533],"+
                "[44,128446],"+
                "[45,139854],"+
                "[46,152196],"+
                "[47,164734],"+
                "[48,178446],"+
                "[49,192185],"+
                "[50,206185],"+
                "[51,221798],"+
                "[52,237983],"+
                "[53,256007],"+
                "[54,273350],"+
                "[55,293178],"+
                "[56,312529],"+
                "[57,333228],"+
                "[58,354387],"+
                "[59,374656],"+
                "[60,397386],"+
                "[61,422795],"+
                "[62,447954],"+
                "[63,474574],"+
                "[64,502022],"+
                "[65,528116],"+
                "[66,508208],"+
                "[67,489122],"+
                "[68,469393],"+
                "[69,446790],"+
                "[70,425620],"+
                "[71,399269],"+
                "[72,374341],"+
                "[73,347950],"+
                "[74,320046],"+
                "[75,289477],"+
                "[76,259481],"+
                "[77,226566],"+
                "[78,195239],"+
                "[79,161137],"+
                "[80,124524],"+
                "[81,87936],"+
                "[82,49105],"+
                "[83,9223],"+
                "[84,0],"+
                "[85,0],"+
                "[86,0],"+
                "[87,0],"+
                "[88,0],"+
                "[89,0]";
        }

        if(range=='50%'){
            return     "['Age','Savings'],"+
                "[25,0],"+
                "[26,2777],"+
                "[27,5945],"+
                "[28,9525],"+
                "[29,13621],"+
                "[30,18246],"+
                "[31,23263],"+
                "[32,28752],"+
                "[33,34709],"+
                "[34,41703],"+
                "[35,47927],"+
                "[36,55348],"+
                "[37,63149],"+
                "[38,71133],"+
                "[39,79953],"+
                "[40,89218],"+
                "[41,98820],"+
                "[42,109074],"+
                "[43,119427],"+
                "[44,130599],"+
                "[45,142195],"+
                "[46,154751],"+
                "[47,167842],"+
                "[48,182056],"+
                "[49,195975],"+
                "[50,210944],"+
                "[51,227013],"+
                "[52,243238],"+
                "[53,262412],"+
                "[54,280982],"+
                "[55,301273],"+
                "[56,321808],"+
                "[57,344012],"+
                "[58,365755],"+
                "[59,386597],"+
                "[60,411162],"+
                "[61,438555],"+
                "[62,463823],"+
                "[63,494641],"+
                "[64,523299],"+
                "[65,551297],"+
                "[66,537169],"+
                "[67,516997],"+
                "[68,502759],"+
                "[69,483642],"+
                "[70,462924],"+
                "[71,439222],"+
                "[72,417198],"+
                "[73,391691],"+
                "[74,367612],"+
                "[75,341845],"+
                "[76,312223],"+
                "[77,282649],"+
                "[78,249556],"+
                "[79,220004],"+
                "[80,186632],"+
                "[81,152438],"+
                "[82,114808],"+
                "[83,77722],"+
                "[84,38624],"+
                "[85,0],"+
                "[86,0],"+
                "[87,0],"+
                "[88,0],"+
                "[89,0]";
        }

        if(range=='60%'){
            return     "['Age','Savings'],"+
                "[25,0],"+
                "[26,2786],"+
                "[27,5971],"+
                "[28,9570],"+
                "[28,13704],"+
                "[30,18373],"+
                "[31,23443],"+
                "[32,28982],"+
                "[33,35048],"+
                "[34,41489],"+
                "[35,48454],"+
                "[36,55997],"+
                "[37,63928],"+
                "[38,72082],"+
                "[39,81085],"+
                "[40,90335],"+
                "[41,100141],"+
                "[42,110564],"+
                "[43,121448],"+
                "[44,132626],"+
                "[45,144297],"+
                "[46,157620],"+
                "[47,171060],"+
                "[48,185356],"+
                "[49,199957],"+
                "[50,215204],"+
                "[51,231915],"+
                "[52,249507],"+
                "[53,268765],"+
                "[54,288130],"+
                "[55,308893],"+
                "[56,330782],"+
                "[57,354500],"+
                "[58,378065],"+
                "[59,399396],"+
                "[60,425435],"+
                "[61,455705],"+
                "[62,481828],"+
                "[63,513748],"+
                "[64,545058],"+
                "[65,574577],"+
                "[66,564651],"+
                "[67,548752],"+
                "[68,536922],"+
                "[69,517938],"+
                "[70,500535],"+
                "[71,478030],"+
                "[72,458729],"+
                "[73,437272],"+
                "[74,415832],"+
                "[75,393035],"+
                "[76,367364],"+
                "[77,336848],"+
                "[78,306959],"+
                "[79,279837],"+
                "[80,248487],"+
                "[81,213600],"+
                "[82,181529],"+
                "[83,147792],"+
                "[84,112113],"+
                "[85,76294],"+
                "[86,39301],"+
                "[87,104],"+
                "[88,0],"+
                "[89,0]";
                ;
        }

        if(range=='70%'){
            return     "['Age','Savings'],"+
                "[25,0],"+
                "[26,2794],"+
                "[27,5993],"+
                "[28,9618],"+
                "[29,13779],"+
                "[30,18504],"+
                "[31,23631],"+
                "[32,29320],"+
                "[33,35387],"+
                "[34,41911],"+
                "[35,48993],"+
                "[36,56634],"+
                "[37,64692],"+
                "[38,72983],"+
                "[39,82101],"+
                "[40,91570],"+
                "[41,101540],"+
                "[42,112196],"+
                "[43,123369],"+
                "[44,134976],"+
                "[45,146856],"+
                "[46,160860],"+
                "[47,174187],"+
                "[48,189197],"+
                "[49,204699],"+
                "[50,220890],"+
                "[51,237571],"+
                "[52,256558],"+
                "[53,276256],"+
                "[54,296966],"+
                "[55,318733],"+
                "[56,342416],"+
                "[57,366487],"+
                "[58,391413],"+
                "[59,415809],"+
                "[60,443588],"+
                "[61,474867],"+
                "[62,503044],"+
                "[63,534527],"+
                "[64,570607],"+
                "[65,601668],"+
                "[66,595372],"+
                "[67,583042],"+
                "[68,574661],"+
                "[69,559823],"+
                "[70,543853],"+
                "[71,526871],"+
                "[72,506862],"+
                "[73,492386],"+
                "[74,472854],"+
                "[75,451655],"+
                "[76,429040],"+
                "[77,403881],"+
                "[78,380852],"+
                "[79,353785],"+
                "[80,326895],"+
                "[81,296793],"+
                "[82,269441],"+
                "[83,240067],"+
                "[84,205984],"+
                "[85,176523],"+
                "[86,143190],"+
                "[87,105151],"+
                "[88,69312],"+
                "[89,33088],";
        }


    });






}
//Activate knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[name='range']").change(function(){
     buffer();
   });
})
```

here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/aL73X/6/

Comment: This is not the answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score 22):

A computed observable is generally used to return a calculated value.  Any observables (or other computeds) that are accessed as part of the computed's evaluation will become dependencies and trigger it to run again. A computed can be used like a subscription and is especially useful when you want to subscribe to multiple observables at once.  However, you will not know which dependency triggered the change.

A manual subscription is specific to a single observable (or computed) and is passed the new value as its first argument. There is no concept of creating dependencies in the execution of the subscription's handler, as it will only ever be triggered when this observable changes.

Comment: So which is more advisable to use in case I want to capture a change in a hidden input programatically?

Comment: so do you have a hidden input that is bound against your view model using the `value` binding?

Comment: yes through computed function im able to get what I was looking for I tried using subscription so it may trigger an onchange like event but no dice :)

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample in jsFiddle, but it sounds like you got it working.

Comment: oh sorry btw, here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a_miguel6687/aL73X/4/  how can I use my radio buttons as a computed function then output my results to an input box through jquery im able to do this but there seems to be a delay when I changed the value per radio button

Comment: Another difference is if you call anObservable.notifySubscribers(newValue), the newValue can be accessed in subscribe function as the first param, but not in computed.

Answer (score 8):

In short, a computed is kind of like a getter/setter property and mainly for calculated values.  Subscribe is a kind of callback function that you can add/remove from a `subscribable` object, which observables and computeds derive from.

By default, a subscription subscribes to a topic called 'change', and would look like this when explicitly defined:

```
var obs = ko.observable();
obs.subscribe(function(newValue) { ... }, null, 'change');
```

There is another built in topic you can subscribe to called 'beforeChange' and the value passed in is the old value:

```
obs.subscribe(function(oldValue) { ... }, null, 'beforeChange');
```

You can also create your own custom topics to watch and 'publish' to if you'd like, something like this:

```
obs.subscribe(function(newValue) { ... }, null, 'customTopic');
obs("Hello World");// When this updates, 'change' and 'beforeChange' subscriptions are called.
obs.notifySubscribers('customTopic');// This is 'publishing' the new value to anyone subscribing to this topic.
```

Ryan Niemeyer has a great [video](http://vimeo.com/73627803) on this at 16:35 as well as a [Knockout-Postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox/) plugin based on this concept.

Comment: the video could not be found in case of a hidden input can you use subscribe as well???

Comment: Must not have copied the entire link.  Looks like Ryan corrected it.  Thanks Ryan.

Answer (score 2):

A computed runs through the dependencies to generate a new value that can be bound. A subscribe function is like an event.